# How quick switch between frames?

Tags: frames

windows 10, emacs 26.1

I open 4 frames.
How I can quick switch between them?

I need smt like this:

`C-1`  -> switch to frame#1

`C-2`  -> switch to frame#2

and so on.

I use ace-window but it not very compfortable because:

```
1. Create frame#1 
 2. split it to 2 windows
 3. create frame#2
 4. split it to 3 windows
 5. create frame#3
 6. On screen visible only one frame (e.g. frame#2)
```

And now try to quick switch between frames. It very hard.
Ace-windows show me **6 numbers** (1,2,3,3,4,5,6). And how I select quick desire frames? 
It's hard.

Comment: ace-window might be what you want. See https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window

Comment: No. I use it but when many frames it's not comfortable.

Comment: I am using a combination of ace-window and eybrowse. It allows you to have several workspaces in one frame. See for instance here for the description of eybrowse https://manuel-uberti.github.io/emacs/2017/08/06/eyebrowse/

Comment: Does `other-frame` work under Windows? I have that bound to `C-\``, it allows cycling between frames.

Comment: Work. but  it's not comfortable. Suppose I open 5 frames.I need to use at least "other-frame" any times to select desire frame. It's to hard.

Comment: It is bound to <C-tab>, C-`, C-x 5 o.

(other-frame ARG)  - So <C-tab> is good.

Comment: (global-set-key (kbd "C-<tab>") 'other-frame)  - this help me

Comment: You can give names to your frames (see [Frames](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frames.html#Frames)) and you can list them with `(frame-list)`, so you could construct something similar to what `C-x C-b` does for buffers, with a mode that allows you to click or hit `RET` on an entry to run `select-frame-set-input-focus` on it. Maybe something like that exists already.

Comment: Here is a  link to a slight variation that I use to switch by letter or by number to a different frame:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26922594/2112489  Depending upon your operating system, you may need to change `select-frame` and `raise-frame` to `select-frame-set-input-focus`.  I have a few select letters as options in my own setup, e.g., `m` for main; `M` for miscellaneous; `o` for org-mode; etc.

Answer (score 4):

I use [switch-window](https://github.com/dimitri/switch-window).  When switching windows, it labels each window with a key and then prompts for which one you want.  There are several options, but I prefer to use the home row for the labels.

[image: switch-window]

You can use `(setq switch-window-multiple-frames t)` to have it span multiple frames.

My `init.el` looks like:

```
(use-package switch-window
  :ensure t
  :bind
  ;; default C-x o is other-window
  ;; default C-x C-o is delete-blank-lines
  (("C-x o" . switch-window)
   ("C-x C-o" . switch-window))
  :config
  (setq switch-window-multiple-frames t)
  (setq switch-window-shortcut-style 'qwerty)
  ;; when Emacs is run as client, the first shortcut does not appear
  ;; "x" acts as a dummy; remove first entry if not running server
  (setq switch-window-qwerty-shortcuts '("x" "a" "s" "d" "f" "j" "k" "l" ";" "w" "e" "r" "u" "i" "o" "q" "t" "y" "p"))
  (setq switch-window-increase 3))
```

A minimal setup would look like:

```
(require 'switch-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x o") 'switch-window)
(setq switch-window-multiple-frames t)
```

[image: Minimal setup with multiple frames]

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can quickly select a frame by its name, with completion, using multi-command `icicle-select-frame`:

> **`icicle-select-frame`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   [`icicles-cmd1.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-cmd1.el).
>
> It is bound to `C-x 5 o`.
>
> `(icicle-select-frame)`
>
> Select frame by its name and raise it.
>
> A frame name in this context is suffixed as needed by `[NUMBER]`, to
>   make it unique.  For example, in a context where frames are named for
>   their buffers and you have two frames showing buffer `*Help*`, one of
>   the frames will be called `*Help*[2]` for use with this command.
>
> Read input, then call `icicle-select-frame-by-name`
>   to act on it.

As always for an Icicles [*multi-command*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands):

> Input-candidate completion and cycling are available.  While cycling,
>   these keys with prefix `C-` are active:
>
> `C-mouse-2`, `C-return` - Act on current completion candidate only
>
> `C-down`, `C-wheel-down` - Move to next completion candidate and act
>
> `C-up`, `C-wheel-up` - Move to previous completion candidate and act
>
> `C-next`  - Move to next apropos-completion candidate and act
>
> `C-prior` - Move to previous apropos-completion candidate and act
>
> `C-end`   - Move to next prefix-completion candidate and act
>
> `C-home`  - Move to previous prefix-completion candidate and act
>
> `C-!`     - Act on *all* candidates, successively (careful!)
>
> When candidate action and cycling are combined (e.g. `C-next`), user
>   option `icicle-act-before-cycle-flag` determines which occurs first.
>
> With prefix `C-M-` instead of `C-`, the same keys (`C-M-mouse-2`,
>   `C-M-RET`, `C-M-down`, and so on) provide help about candidates.
>
> Use `mouse-2`, `RET`, or `S-RET` to finally choose a candidate, or
>   `C-g` to quit.
>
> This is an Icicles command - see command `icicle-mode`.

---

An even handier command is `icicle-other-window-or-frame`, bound to `C-x o` by default. It combines several commands for selecting windows or frames.

> **`icicle-other-window-or-frame`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function
>   in [`icicles-cmd1.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-cmd1.el).
>
> It is bound to `C-x o`.
>
> `(icicle-other-window-or-frame ARG)`
>
> Select a window or frame, by name or by order.
>
> This command combines Emacs commands `other-window` and `other-frame`,
>   together with Icicles commands `icicle-select-window`,
>   `icicle-select-frame`, and `icicle-choose-window-for-buffer-display`.
>
> Use the prefix argument to choose the behavior, as follows:
>
> - With no prefix arg or a non-zero numeric prefix arg:
>     If the selected frame has multiple windows, then this is
>     **`other-window`**.  Otherwise, it is **`other-frame`**.
> - With a zero prefix arg (e.g. **`C-0`**):
>     If the selected frame has multiple windows, then this is
>     **`icicle-select-window`** with *windows in the frame* as candidates.
>     Otherwise (single-window frame), this is **`icicle-select-frame`**.
> - With plain **`C-u`**:
>     If the selected frame has multiple windows, then this is
>     **`icicle-select-window`** with *windows from all visible frames* as
>     candidates.  Otherwise, this is **`icicle-select-frame`**.
> - With plain **`C-u C-u`**:
>     Same as **`icicle-select-window`** with a negative prefix arg: *Select a
>     window from any frame*, including iconified and invisible frames.
> - With plain **`C-u C-u C-u`**:
>     This is **`icicle-choose-window-for-buffer-display`**, with windows from
>     all frames (i.e., iconified and invisible) frames as candidates.
>
> If you use library [`oneonone.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/oneonone.el) with a standalone minibuffer frame,
>   and if option `1on1-remap-other-frame-command-flag` is non-`nil`, then
>   frame selection can include the standalone minibuffer frame.
>
> By default, Icicle mode remaps all key sequences that are normally
>   bound to `other-window` to `icicle-other-window-or-frame`.  If you do
>   not want this remapping, then customize option
>   `icicle-top-level-key-bindings`.